# FORMAT function not working in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '01/01/2011';
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-US' ) AS US_Result;
```

I am using above code in SQL Server 2008 R2 but it is encountering an error:

> 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

How can I use `FORMAT` function?

Comment: there is a  cast and convert function in tsql. Format ?

Comment: "How can i use [`FORMAT`](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/24/syndicated/500/posts/12110/sql-server-denali-format-string-function.aspx) function"? Upgrade to 2012. Or write your own CLR function that mimics this one for previous versions.

Comment: There is no format function in sql server. There is a Cast and Convert function which converts one datatype to another. You have to use the convert function

Comment: @WaqarJanjua There is a `FORMAT` function, but only in SQL Server 2012 upwards - as Martin Smith already stated. Just repeating your comment won't change that ;-)

Comment: @Christian.K I don't know that :(

Comment: You can do that as `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @d, 101)` in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @MartinSmith yes you have to upgrade.

Comment: @Christian.K yes it is in sql server 2012

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FORMAT function is available from version 2012 onwards. In earlier versions, use this:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '01/01/2011'; 
SELECT replace(replace(' '+convert(varchar(10),@d,101),' 0',''),'/0','/')
```

However, formatting is the job of the front end application.

Comment: Normally the function should be used after the column or variable. Something like @d.FORMAT('d','en-US')

Answer (score 8):

You can use this:

```
    select convert(varchar(12) , @d , 3)
```

You can find here http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx more standard date formats.

Answer (score 2):

According to: [FORMAT Function (DAX), (SQL Server 2008 R2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634924%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), the FORMAT() function exists in SQL Server 2008 R2...

Edit: As pointed out, the above link is related only to DAX. The correct one ([FORMAT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)) specifies that FORMAT, in T-SQL, is only available starting from SQL Server 2012...

Comment: FWIW, the (DAX) part of that is noting it's part of Data Analysis Expressions, which can only be used in PowerPivot, an Excel 2010 (+?) add-on for giving Excel better tools to connect to external data, including SQL Server 2008.