# How to present Date in SQL without leading zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date-format, date-formatting

Is there a SQL format to remove leading zeros from the date?

Like if the date is `01/12/2015` to present it as `1/12/2015`, and `01/01/2016` should be shown as `1/1/2016` etc

The entire date normally contains `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`. I need to remove those redundant leading zeroes without changing the rest of information.

Currently I use query containing something like this:

```
convert(varchar, dateadd(hh, " + 2 + " , o.start_time), 103)) + ' '  
left(convert(varchar, dateadd(hh, " + 2 + " , o.start_time), 108), 110)
```

I'm working with SQL Server 2008

Comment: What data type are you using to store that date?

Comment: if you are using this data in an application or report, it is better to do this formatting on the front-end and keep the data in its native format when reading from the database.  As soon as you format it on the way out, it is just character data and can no longer be sorted or filtered as a date.

Comment: Have you tried "FORMAT" function... tried on sqlfiddle and this example worked and removed leading zeroes - " SELECT FORMAT ( dateadd(dd, -225, getdate()), 'd/m/y', 'en-US' )"

Comment: I'm retrieving this data from DB to some local hashMap to compare with data retrieved from the web page. The web page presents the data in shortened way, the DB with pre-coming zeros. I prefer converting the Date after quiring the data from DB to hashMap and not to convert data received from the web page to dd/MM/yyyy format

Comment: @vmachan: `FORMAT` is only available in SQL Server **2012** as a new feature - not available in SQL Server **2008** which is used here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this. Here is one way.

- Use [**`DAY`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176052.aspx) and [**`MONTH`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) inbuilt `date` functions to extract `day` and `month`
  from `date`.
- Both the function's **return type** is `INT` which will remove the unwanted leading zero
- Then concatenate the values back to form the `date`

Try something like this

```
declare @date datetime = '01/01/2016'

select cast(day(@date) as varchar(2))+'/'+cast(month(@date) as varchar(2))+'/'+cast(year(@date) as varchar(4))
```

**Result :** 1/1/2016

- [**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6634)

**Note:** Always prefer to store `date` in `date` **datatype**

Answer (score 13):

Try this, format is a much cleaner solution:

```
declare @date datetime = '01/01/2016'    
SELECT FORMAT(@date,'M/d/yyyy')
```

**result:** 1/1/2016

- [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/54433)

Comment: Please note that this solution only words for SQL Server 2012 and later. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11499496/11809641

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `datename()` for the day and year:

```
select cast(month(o.start_time) as varchar(255)) + '/' + datename(day, o.start_time) + '/' + datename(year, o.start_time)
```

An alternative method uses `replace()`:

```
select replace(replace(replace('@month/@day/@year', '@month', month(o.start_time)
                              ), '@day', day(o.start_time)
                      ), '@year', year(o.start_time)
              )
```

Personally, I see no use for this.  I always put days in YYYY-MM-DD format.