# Custom date time formatting - SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to format sql date time as following format

> 2011-04-28 23:53:13 ----->  Thu Apr 28 23:53:13 UTC 2011

unfortunately FORMAT function is not supported in my 2008 SQL Server
it says that

> 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Does your data actually contain the timezone? Doy you wnt to see that timezone? Or is UTC an assumed constant?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11499496/2224701

Comment: Any reason you want to  do that? As in: In 99% of the cases you pull the date and format in the application.

Comment: My original application is ruby + MYSQL which has data export to csv function and all the date time csv outputs are in this messy format, I have migrated same app and data to SQL server and  Kentico,  However I need to genarate same output as it was, Yes UTC is constant

Comment: @KRR just be careful of calling `GETUTCDATE()` multiple times... because each time you call it, you will get a new `UTCDATE`. I recommend to call it only *once* - as I put in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code. I assumed UTC as your constant from your question description

```
   SELECT SUBSTRING(DATENAME(DW,GETUTCDATE()),1,3) + ' ' + 
   SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MM,GETUTCDATE()),1,3) +' '+ 
   CAST(DATEPART(DD,GETUTCDATE()) AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' '
   +cast( cast(GETUTCDATE() as time(0)) as varchar(20)) + ' UTC '+ 
   DATENAME(YY,GETUTCDATE())
```

Comment: I made this as a SQL function and  instead of UTCDATE I used input DateTime parameter

Comment: Its Ok. But when hug data present in SELECT then performance might be slow, because function executes per record basis. However for smaller amount of data there is no issue. Thank you @KRR

Answer (score 0):

`FORMAT` is part of SQL Server 2012 changes from 2008, for older versions of SQL Server, use `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT(SUBSTRING(DATENAME(DW,GETUTCDATE()),1,3)+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETUTCDATE(), 100))
```

The only problem with this is that it doesn't have timezone. Is your database datetime logs saved with UTC(Based on good practices, it should)? If yes, then you can append the string  'UTC' to the following query.