# How to Print the query results in desired format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Basically i am trying to create a post deployment Script which will merge my data to the DB on deployment. I have around 10K rows which need to be printed in specific format. So formatting 10K rows of data is quiet time consuming.

Here is my table schema

```
Table1 
{
UniqueId  (UniqueIdentifier),
Name  (nvarchar(100)),
Number (int)
}
```

i would like to print the results in below format

```
('{23AA00D7-5187-429C-8A5B-CA64906EECF3}','Tom',1),
('{53AA00D7-5187-429C-8A5B-CA64906EECF3}','Bill',30),
('{AAAA00D7-5187-429C-8A5B-CA64996EECF3}','Gary',21)
```

Please let me know if i can do this using a query .

Comment: Which RDBMS is this? What have you already tried? It seems like fairly simply casting and string concatenation to me.

Comment: Yes each row formatted in the same manner as i mentioned above. And i am using SQL 2008

Comment: You might have a look at [this question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499396/format-function-not-working-in-sql-server-2008-r2) for some ideas.

Comment: Please tag the post with the SQL version and add the column types to your schema.

Comment: @underscore_d i have done edits as per ur comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be doable using just use simple `cast`ing and string concatenation. Try this and let me know how it looks.

```
select '(''{' + cast(UniqueId as varchar) + '}'',''' + Name + ''',' + cast(Number as varchar) + '),'
from Table1;

-- Now remove the final trailing comma.
```

Alternatively, the `+` operator could be replaced with `concat(stringPart1, stringPart2, etc)`.